Is there a way to force plugins to use Flyway migrations for database changes?
Can I somehow force Wordpress plugins to output their required database changes as part of updates rather than let them change the database directly?
Coming from Java Spring Boot development, one of the most convenient ways to update databases in a development/production environment is to use Flyway for database changes. Essentially every database change gets checked in as a separate file that contains the SQL code needed to update the database structure. These migration files are then part of the versioning system and upon deployment will create the same structural changes to my live database.
In order for this to work, all database changes would have to go through Flyway (migrations) though and I'm not sure if there is a reasonably convenient way to do that with things like installing new plugins or updating existing ones.
